# ASP.NET MVC 3 _Layout.cshtml Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Can anyone help me with the subject? I'm using Razor view engine and I need to pass some data to _Layout. How can I do it?

Answer (score 10):

As usual you start by creating a view model representing the data:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string SomeData { get; set; }
}
```

then a controller which will fetch the data from somewhere:

```
public class MyDataController: Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new MyViewModel
        {
            SomeData = "some data"
        };
        return PartialView(model);
    }
}
```

then a corresponding view (`~/Views/MyData/Index.cshtml`) to represent the data:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<h2>@Model.SomeData</h2>
```

and finally inside your `_Layout.cshtml` include this data somewhere:

```
@Html.Action("index", "mydata")
```

Comment: This would imply you have to add this manually to every view. Is there a way to pass data to the _layout.cshtml for every page?

Comment: @Anthony Gatlin, absolutely not. You could perfectly fine write `@Html.Action("index", "mydata")` in your _Layout => which would of course automatically add it to every page of your application that uses this layout.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [ViewBag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controllerbase.viewbag%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) to pass data.

In your controller:

```
ViewBag.LayoutModel = myData;
```

Access in you layout:

```
@ViewBag.LayoutModel
```

It is a dynamic object, so you can use any property name you want.

Answer (score 1):

The ViewBag method is the easiest. However if you need advanced and typed features, you can also try taking that part to a partial view (the part that'll render the dependent section) with a common controller (if the value can be calculated on it's own and doesn't need input from other controllers), and call RenderPartial on it from _Layout.
If you'd like I can give you some more info about it...

Comment: Yes, please, give us some more info about it :]