# Rendering Global Title

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, layout, viewbag

I am trying to pull from the database a saved Title.  I want it to load every time without using the view to call it.   So I want a variable to be pulled when I call it from the Layout.  How can I do this?

In Layout Example:

```
@ViewBag.ShowTitle
```

This would show to every single page that renders the layout.  I'm not sure how I would call the field from the database to the screen without a controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call a [`PartialView`](http://rachelappel.com/razor/partial-views-in-asp-net-mvc-3-w-the-razor-view-engine/) in your `_Layout.cshtml` page.

```
@Html.Partial("_Title")
```

but you do need a `Controller` to interact with the database and to assign the `Title` value to the `ViewBag`.

**PartialView**

```
<div>
    <h2>
        @ViewBag.ShowTitle
    </h2>
</div>
```

---

You can also do as described in the following link where you define a `ViewModel`, a `Controller` and calls `@Html.Action` inside `_Layout.cshtml`:

[ASP.NET MVC 3 _Layout.cshtml Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4692977/114029)

Comment: Is there a way to not use the controller? I find that I have to add the title for every single page and it seems a little too much work for something so small.

Comment: No... you do need a controller in this case.

Comment: So if I needed to change the code, I would have to do it for the controller and the view for X amount of pages.  That seems like back tracking.

Comment: The title is the same on every page and controller pertains to a specific page.  In order for me to set a the ViewBag, wouldn't I need to create the call in the Controller of every page?

Comment: Not really. See the example in the link provided in the answer. When he calls `Html.Action("index", "mydata")`, he is telling that he wants the `index` action method implemented in the `mydata` controller. The controller can be like a `global` controller with action methods to be called by any view you have in your app. There's nothing that implies that a controller is specific to a single view. Hope you get the idea.

Comment: What I'm saying is that I have to set the controller to set the ViewBag for the Partial to display.  If I need to change something then I have change the return code for every view that sets that variable or if I need to change something drastic.

Comment: No... you'll have to change only the Controller code and the partial HTML code. That's why you're defining it the `_Layout.cshtml` in the first place: to avoid repetition following the DRY principle.

Comment: I think I was misunderstanding something.  I didn't know you could use Action like that.  Thank you, I got it to work.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid using a controller only if your database support direct web access (like Raven DB http://ravendb.net/docs/http-api).

But you can also use a trick with a session. For example you can read and save the title to Session in global.asax and use the session variable on the page, but it's very bad to write code like that.

Comment: Yeah, I avoided the session method.  I did find something similar though.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10094861/how-can-i-set-a-variable-on-a-layout-page